# 1-loop 4-point Feynman diagrams of four-fermion interactions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, fermions

Consider the Lagrangian
$$\mathcal L = \bar\psi(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu -\sigma)\psi +\frac{c}{2}\bar\psi\psi\bar\psi\psi.$$
I would like to calculate the $4$-point fermion interaction amplitude to one-loop order. For this, I first wrote down the diagram expansion, i.e.

[image]

where $p:=p_3+p_4=-p_1-p_2$. This is where my problems occur..

- Apparently, there are 5 diagrams at one-loop order, but I don't see where they are supposed to come from.
- My second problem is that I'm unsure about writing down the amplitude for the above diagram. My attempt is $$ (ic)^2\int \frac{d^4k}{(2 \pi)^4} \frac{\mathrm{Tr}[i(\gamma^\mu k_\mu +\sigma)i(\gamma^\nu(p-k)_\nu+\sigma)]}{(k^2-\sigma^2)((p-k)^2-\sigma^2)} \bar u_3u_1\bar u_4u_2 $$ Does this make sense? Do we need a minus sign for the fermion loop? Did I pick the momenta properly?

I think the above amplitude I wrote down is wrong because the spinors $u_k$ are in the wrong position. They should be between the propagators, but then I don't know what to do with the trace. Four-fermion interactions seem a bit weird to me at the moment...

Comment: Reg your first question: each of the four external lines has a one loop correction.

Comment: You can exchange the bubble in all three of the $s$, $t$ and $u$ channels.